# Any elegant way to 'override' a No Bulk Mail setting for a single mailing?

Tags: civimail

One of our client organizations is sending newsletters to their 4000 members on a regular basis; about 400 of them are not interested in bulk mail and have the No Bulk Mail switch set to On. Once a year though there is a statutory meeting that requires that an invitation is sent to all members, overriding the NoBulkMail setting. So far I've only found awkward ways to arrange for this (moving the members involved into a dedicated group, removing the switch, sending the mail, moving switch back on). Any ideas on how to solve this more elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the no bulk email flag isn't, and shouldn't be an easy process, so what you describe seems to be the "less cumbersome" possible way indeed.

However, it seems to point out to a related issue: these 400 people shouldn't have opted out, but rather it seems should have been unsubscribed from the "regular" newsletter group and kept into the "VIP statutory meeting announcement only" group.

In theory, you can't really reach out to people that have opted out -by definition- but given your specific situation, I would contact them to tell them that you need to be able to mail them, and explain the new "statutory meeting" vs. "newsletter" situation.